# jmespath sort whole string as one

Tags: aws-cli, jmespath

I'm trying to sort a numerical field however it seems to parse each character in turn so 9 is 'higher' than 11' but lower than 91

Is there a way to sort by the whole string?

Example data:

```
{
  "testing": [
    {"name": "01"},
    {"name": "3"},
    {"name": "9"},
    {"name": "91"},
    {"name": "11"},
    {"name": "2"}
  ]
}
```

Query:

`reverse(sort_by(testing, &name))[*].[name]`

result:

```
  [
    "91"
  ],
  [
    "9"
  ],
  [
    "3"
  ],
  [
    "2"
  ],
  [
    "11"
  ],
  [
    "01"
  ]
]
```

This can be tried at http://jmespath.org/

edit:
So I can get the correct output by piping it to sort -V but is there not an easier way?

Answer (score 2):

### Context

- Jmespath latest version as of 2020-09-12

### Use-case

- DevBobDylan wants to sort string items in a JSON ArrayOfObject table

### Solution

- use Jmespath pipe operator to chain expressions together

### Example

```
testing|[*].name|sort(@)
```

### Screenshot

[image: Result using the Jmespath.org REPL]